# Find begining of word in string from index at middle of word

Tags: regex, vb.net

So I have a list of integers, they are of the index of a character inside a word that I would like to select. My list is `selMid` what I would like to do is find the **index** for the first letter of the word, and then the last letter, so that I can get a **length** of the word. For example, imagine I'm double clicking on a word, and it highlights only the word, that is a similar functionality that I would like to achieve. Right now the code that I do have works, but only if the word begins with a `(`. I would need it work with probably all special characters. I was thinking of using regex, but I'm having trouble implementing it, the match pattern that I have commented out I think would work, but I can't figure out how to start it looking from an index position in the string.

```
Public loopChar As Char
Public loopCharIndex As Integer
Public successBool As Boolean

Public Function indexSelection()
       For Each item In selMid
        Do
            'Dim pattern As String = "\b"
            'Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(RichTextBox1.Text.ToString, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
            loopChar = GetChar(RichTextBox1.Text.ToString, item + 1)
            Console.Write(loopChar)
            loopCharIndex = item + 1
            item = item - 1
        Loop Until (Asc(loopChar) = 40)
        'If m.Success Then
        'Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1} {2}.", m.Value, m.Index, m.Value.ToString.Count)
        'successBool = True
        'End If
        'Loop Until (successBool)

        Console.WriteLine(loopCharIndex)
    Next
    End Function
```

Hopefully my question makes sense,

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this (and I'll freely admit it may not be the best method) by looking for word boundaries backwards and forwards in the string using [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Try something like this:

```
Dim reF As Regex = New Regex("(.*?)\b")
Dim reB As Regex = New Regex("(.*?)\b", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
Dim word as String = String.Empty

If reB.IsMatch(RichTextBox1.Text, selMid - 1) Then
    word = reB.Match(RichTextBox1.Text, selMid - 1).Groups(1).Value
End If

If reF.IsMatch(RichTextBox1.Text, selMid) Then
    word &= reF.Match(RichTextBox1.Text, selMid).Groups(1).Value
End If
```

So, basically this starts searching from one character behind your `selMid` value, looking from right to left (matching backwards in the string), then searches the opposite way starting from `selMid` (ensuring the two searches do not overlap).  Matching any characters up to a word boundary in a non-greedy manner, it should find just the word that `selMid` is in.